# Get Value From JSON decode in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have tried but still not working fine. I have one array that i get from JSON decode in PHP file, I use Ajax for send this array from javascript, this is how i get array.

```
$q = json_decode($_GET['q'], true);
```

I do var_dump this variable and this is the result:

```
array(2) 
{ [0]=> array(1) 
  { ["data"]=> array(2) 
     { ["Text1"]=> string(1) "Car 1" ["Text2"]=> string(1) "Car 2" } 
  }
 [1]=> array(1) 
  { ["data"]=> array(2) 
     { ["Text1"]=> string(1) "Car 3" ["Text2"]=> string(1) "Car 4" } 
  } 
}
```

My question is, how do i get value like "Car 1" or "Car 2" etc from this array? this array like 2 dimensional array, i difficult to get this value. i have found many post related it, i try, but still not solved. Really need help please..

Comment: can you edit your question with array also

Comment: my question was edited, do you have an idea or advice?

Comment: I have written your array like this $json = '{"Text1":"car","Text2":"car2"}'; ? is it ok for you?

Comment: is imposible with 2d array? i mean, by using 2d array, i can differ, this is the first post, and this is the second post,.. so it can be posted accumulatively to database..

Comment: by using $json = '{"Text1":"car","Text2":"car2"}'; this array you can easily get values of car1 and car2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74073/discussion-between-user-and-ugy-astro).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
foreach($pass_your_array as $ta)
{
    if(isset($ta['data']))
    {
        foreach ($ta['data'] as $text)
        {
            $txt1 = $text['Text1'];  // gives car1
            $txt2 = $text['Text2'];  // gives car2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank's for reply, i have tried, but still not completely work. From your example, i combine with query, the output like :
 
insert into employee values Text1-Text1
insert into employee values Text2-Text2

The plan is, from this array we can post to database by looping as many as count of array.